# Scale bones not working (ctrl+alt+s)

Tags: bones

I'm trying to scale my bones but it is not working, i try it in pose mode, edit mode and nothing

you can see it's changing something but no the bone, ScaleB x,y,z always start at 1 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In armature settings you need to swich type to **B-Bone** or **Envelope** to see the difference.

[image]